# Splitting big strings conditionally

Tags: string, vba, excel

How to separate a big string which is comma dellmited, as in `"Hi,there,bob"` and the result is `hi` `there` `bob` using vba.

```
Sub split_letters()
    Dim single_item As Variant, item_var As Variant
    Dim word_list As Variant

    item_var = [{"A,B,C,D","K,L,M,N"}]
    word_list = Split(item_var, ",")

    For Each single_item In word_list
        r = r + 1: Cells(r, 1) = single_item
    Next single_item
End Sub
```

Btw, I could have done it using `word_list = Split("A,B,C,D", ",")` but i wish to do the same in which the string will be passed from a list as in `item_var` holds then it will be split like `word_list` trying to do and finally i will get the result like `A` `B` `C` `D`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop for this:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim s As String, ary

    s = "qwerty,poiu,a,b,c,d,e"
    ary = Split(s, ",")
    Range("A1").Resize(1, UBound(ary) + 1) = ary
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this is it. Thanks Gary's Student, for your robust solution. I was not around so late for the reply.